# Rearranging a muldimensional array to a matrix and preserving the determinant

Tags: determinant

Considering $A$ a multidimensional array $n\times\cdots \times n$ ($n$ repeated $2p$ times), is there any way to arrange its elements in a $n^p\times n^p$ matrix $\widehat{A}$ such that $\det \widehat{A} = \det A$ ?

Comment: How is $\det {A}$ defined?

Comment: It is defined the following way: 
\begin{equation}
\det{A} = \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{i_1^{(1)}=1}^n\cdots\sum_{i_n^{(1)}=1}^n\cdots
\sum_{i_1^{(q)}=1}^n\cdots\sum_{i_n^{(q)}=1}^n\epsilon_{i_1^{(1)}\cdots
 i_n^{(1)}}\cdots\epsilon_{i_1^{(q)}\cdots i_n^{(q)}}
\prod_{k=1}^{n}A_{i_k^{(1)}\cdots i_k^{(q)}}
\end{equation}